# Two codimension one foliations of a Lie group whose Godbilon–Vey invariants are not the same

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, foliations

What is an example  of  a Lie  group $G$ with two codimension one  foliations  $F_1 $  and  $F_2$ such that they generate two different  Godbilon–Vey invariants in $H^3(G)$?

Comment: Are the foliations meant to be left-invariant? If not, Thurston constructed, given any hyperbolic polygon $P \subset \mathbb{H}^2$, a foliation on $S^3$ with Goldbillon-Vey invariant $4\pi \cdot \mathrm{Area}(P)$. (See Thurston's 1972 paper "Noncobordant foliations of $S^3$".)

Comment: @KSackel  Thank  you very  much  for  your very interesting answer. Yes I mean arbitrary  foliation not  necessarilly invariant one.  So your  answer is  very  helpful. BTW what can be said about Godbilon Vey invariant of invariant  foliations?

Comment: A left invariant distribution is an element of $\mathbb{P}\mathfrak{g}^*$. The condition of being a foliation is carved out by quadratic polynomials, and each of these has a refinement of the GV invariant to $H^3(\mathfrak{g};\mathbb{R})$; for $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$, assuming I computed correctly, you can get an arbitrary element of $H^3(\mathfrak{g};\mathbb{R})$. I don't know of an example off-hand in which the image in the de Rham cohomology $H^3(G;\mathbb{R})$ is nonzero.